# Construction of infinite state space model in reinforcement learning

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

Are there any materials or lectures on infinite state space model in reinforcement learning ? Or How to proceed creating an environment which can have infinite state space. I'm looking to generate text through reinforcement learning, so any guidance on above would also be helpful.

Comment: I think you mean "continuous" not "infinite". And also SO does not allow asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

There is lecture [pdf](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes12.pdf) from cs229 course given by Andrew Ng. Fourth topic is about continuous states in MDP. I didn't read that but it can be useful for you. At least you would understand a different concept. I hope you will like it.